# touch: /Users/username/.zshrc: No such file or directory

Tags: zsh, macos, touch

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.2.

Tried to fix python by adding it to .zshrc:

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/username/.zshrc
```

Seems like the file is gone, so I attempted to recreate it:

```
touch ~/.zshrc
touch: /Users/username/.zshrc: No such file or directory
```

No luck. What is going on? How might I fix this?

Comment: Do you have something called `~/.zshrc`? What does `ls -ld ~/.zshrc` output? I'm thinking it could be a broken symbolic link.

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  staff  49 Oct  5  2020 /Users/username/.zshrc -> /Users/username/code/uname/dotfiles/zshrc

Comment: And I'm assuming that `/Users/username/code/uname/dotfiles/zshrc` does not exist?

Comment: true. is there an easy way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file `~/.zshrc` is a symbolic link to a name in a directory that does not exist.  This means appending to the file will fail in the way you show, and touching the file will also fail similarly.

To resolve this, you may either try to recreate the correct symbolic link or remove the broken one and replace it with an actual regular file.

To recreate `~/.zshrc` as a symbolic link to the *correct* pathname, figure out where it is supposed to be pointing to, then use

```bash
ln -s -f ~/the/correct/path/zshrc ~/.zshrc
```

(Unfortunately, I can't tell what the correct pathname is supposed to be.)

To remove the broken link, use

```bash
rm ~/.zshrc
```

You may then append the alias definition to the end of the file with the `echo` command as you initially tried to do.